# Rails: Single button boolean form - determining whether to post to :create or :delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have an app that allows a user to track a song on different websites. A User has_many :trackables and has_many :songs through :trackables.

:trackables table has song_id, user_id, and website

On my index page, I render all @songs. Each song has 3 icons and each icon is an ajax form that, when clicked, posts to trackables_controller with :website as "spotify", "rdio", or "songza" depending on the icon clicked.

If the user has *never* clicked the icon before, form should post to :create. If the icon was already clicked, but clicked again, form should post to :delete.

I hope that makes sense. I suppose I could just post to create, check if identical record exists (and if so delete). I'm trying to figure out the Railsy way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there should be `toggle` action in `TrackablesController` that all three forms point to (but with different song_id and website params). And the logic that creates/deletes trackable should be placed in model Trackable, like so:

```
class Trackable < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def self.toggle(user, song, website)
    existing_trackable = where(user_id: user.id, song_id: song.id, website: website)

    if existing_trackable.present?
      existing_trackable.destroy_all
    else
      create(user_id: user.id, song_id: song.id, website: website)
    end
  end
end
```

And it's called likes so:

```
class TrackableControllers < ApplicationController
  def toggle
    return render json: false unless user_signed_in?
    song = Song.find(params[:song_id])
    return render json: false unless song.present?

    Trackable.toggle(current_user, song, params[:website])
    render json: true
  end
end
```

It's not CRUD, yep, but it's still REST: there's a resource (Trackable) and there's an action (toggle).

Comment: Ah nice. One question about this method... I'd like to add a class to the @trackables submit button to let user know what state it is in (e.g. darker if the Trackable record exists for that song/website).  But how do I easily check the state for Trackables when I am rendering all my trackables ? There will be ~50 trackables per page so it seems bad to be querying the database on each trackable to see if it exists

Comment: <%= form_for @trackable, :remote => true do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :website, :value=> "spotify" %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :song_id, :value=> "#{song.id}" %>
      <%= image_submit_tag('spotify.png', :class=>"img-responsive") %>
    <% end %>    AND I would want to add "pushed" or something to the image_submit if that trackable exists

Comment: You don't need to load each trackable, instead you can preload all of them (well, not absolutely all, but only those that belong to the songs you load). Just add `.preload(:trackables)` (it's for song has_many :trackables relation) to the command that loads songs in `index` action.

You can also implement `tracked?` instance method in Song model, that accepts user and website, and checks certain trackable for existence. So the code will be cleaner in the view.